# ViewModel doesn't update ui after Activity and Fragment was created second time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have an app which is opened/started from outside via PWA. Then data is fetched from a service and passed to the UI via a Shared ViewModel. When I start the app for the first time it's working fine. When I start it again, ui will not be updated anymore, even if I receive tracking informations. My guess is that it is because the app is destroyed and re-created. However, the .observe is also reassigned so it should workout.

**In Fragment**

```
    private val locationUpdateViewModel: LocationUpdateViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        locationUpdateViewModel.uiElapsedTime.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { elapsedTime ->
                updateElapsedTime(elapsedTime)
        }

        startTracking()
    }
```

**In ViewModel**

```
val uiElapsedTime: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

fun locationReceived(){
    ...
    uiElapsedTime.postValue("$time")
}
```

Unfortunately moving startTracking() or Observing to onStart() or onResume() didn't help. I added different logs of every lifecycle process. Attached you can see two things i did.

1. When switching to another app and back = WORKING

```
   2022-03-18 10:30:27.168 16851-16851/de.locations D/TAG: Activity onRestart
   2022-03-18 10:30:27.197 16851-16851/de.locations D/TAG: TrackDetailLiveFragment onCreate
   2022-03-18 10:30:27.430 16851-16851/de.locations D/TAG: Service is running: true 
   2022-03-18 10:30:28.002 16851-16851/de.locations D/TAG: TrackDetailLiveFragment onResume
   2022-03-18 10:30:28.002 16851-16851/de.locations D/TAG: locationUpdateViewModel.loadActiveTrackData()
   2022-03-18 10:30:47.540 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive
   2022-03-18 10:30:47.543 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG VIEMODEL: speed 132.79279558118925 distance 404.7006743398197 totalDistance 0.81766925647099 elapsedTime 18 syncWithAPI false
```

2. When opening app again via pwa = NOT WORKING

```
   2022-03-18 10:36:37.517 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: Activity destroyed
   2022-03-18 10:36:37.609 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: TrackDetailLiveFragment onDestroy
   2022-03-18 10:36:38.150 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: Activity onCreate
   2022-03-18 10:36:38.211 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: TrackDetailLiveFragment onCreate
   2022-03-18 10:36:38.312 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: Service is running: true 
   2022-03-18 10:36:38.594 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: TrackDetailLiveFragment onStart
   2022-03-18 10:36:38.608 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: TrackDetailLiveFragment onResume
   2022-03-18 10:36:38.608 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: locationUpdateViewModel.loadActiveTrackData()
   2022-03-18 10:36:47.540 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG: BroadcastReceiver onReceive
   2022-03-18 10:36:47.543 17461-17461/de.locations D/TAG VIEMODEL: speed 133.79279505888925 distance 401.7009233398197 totalDistance 0.81762263647099 elapsedTime 22 syncWithAPI false
```

Comment: try to subscribe on onStart

Comment: Unfortunately not. I added logs to my origin post.

Answer (score 1):

After days i found the problem and solution. (Re)-creating the fragment and updating viewmodel worked as it should. The problem was, that i used the "old" BroadcastReveiver. I use a Service to receive location updates any my BroadcastReceiver listens for changes. I had to unregister and register again.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the app starts again, the Activity or Fragment is not recreated. Because when it first time starts, it works.

According to your code, I think your fragment must not recreate, if your fragment is resued, we should in the `OnActivityCreate` to restore the data, Because the fragment is not created when it is resued, so the `onViewCreate`
the method will not be called in that situation.

At the same time, the observer should only add the `onCreate` method to avoid adding it many times.

so move the `startTracking()` method to `onResume` or `onActivityCreate`

Comment: Unfortunately not. I added logs to my origin post. Here you can see, that Activity is destroyed and created again.

Comment: @ManuelWenner, if that, firstly, you should check if the data changed, then the update the UI method whether called, the view content if changed. I think maybe it is not the ViewModel problem.